# Render a Custom form with form action within index of an active admin resource

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using active admin in my application. I came across a situation where I want to add a form in the default resource page along with index. So what I did is ,

> ```
> ActiveAdmin.register Post do
>    index do
>      column : mycolumn
>      panel 'Enter Details' do
>        render partial : 'my semantic form'
>      end
>    end
> end
> ```

My semantic form has 2 drop down fields and a submit button. On clicking the submit button an action has to be called .What happens here is the inputs are displayed clumsy

```
 1. Is there a way to display the form elements in expected way
 2. I don't know where to define the form action upon clicking the submit button
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this, but if you really must take a look at this article on [adding popup modals to the index page](https://helabs.com/artigos/2014/05/28/quick-add-and-quick-edit-on-active-admin/). There are some additional articles on the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#index-pages-filters-and-scopes).